# How can I remove the label from heat shrink tubing?

Tags: cables

I want to use heat shrink tubing on the jacks of an instrument cable I'm making (like in the photo below). The problem is that the tubing I have has a label printed on the side with the size and such, and I don't think I'd be able to find any that doesn't. I really don't want a label like that on the cable - it looks ugly. I've tried sanding it with 400-grit sandpaper, which is the highest grit I have on hand. The label definitely comes off, but it's fairly easy to see scratches left behind on the tubing. If I were to use finer sandpaper, would I have better luck? If not, is there another solution available?

(Note: Apologies if this question is posted in the wrong place. I wasn't sure exactly where to post it.)

[image: instrument cable w/ heat shrink tubing example]

Comment: i have never seen heatshrink tubing with printing before, except tubing that is already applied by a manufacturer ... try using various solvents ... start with water

Comment: Our heatshrink printer's "ink" or whatever it uses comes off with rubbing alcohol or acetone.  I would test a little bit and see if that works, maybe with a q-tip to keep it off the other parts.  You don't want it eating the overbraid or the insulation underneath.

Comment: yeah, buying unprinted tubing is probably the easiest solution here.

Comment: @vir I definitely think I'll try that before anything else, since I already have both tubing and rubbing alcohol.

Comment: Update: The first thing I found was acetone, and it worked perfectly! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**91% alcohol**

It removes *anything* applied to a material, without damaging the surface of the material itself. (Acetone can "smear" some plastics, especially when you apply a lot of acetone at once.)

91% alcohol will remove printed inks, applied paints, etc., from hard surfaces.  I use it to remove unsightly logos, manufacturing marks, etc.

In fact, I remove Sharpie marker writing from almost any hard surface with 91% alcohol.

It also cleans off black smudge marks, greases, oils, foreign material, fingerprints, you name it.
I routinely run orange extension cables thru a rag I've wetted with 91% alcohol, to remove label gum, black marks, etc.  They look brand new.

You have two ways to use it:

If a surface can handle having all of the "surface markings" removed, I will spray it with 91% alchohol and cover it with a plastic bag, to help prevent evaporation.  Give it 5 mins and test.  It might need a 2nd go.

If a surface needs to have some surface marking remain (i.e.: a keyboard), I spray a rag fairly well with 91% alcohol and then wipe the surface.  A rag that's too wet to wiping too much will remove the paint on the keys, so test on the underside, first!

Don't bother using anything lower than 91%.  Lower percentage alcohol will be a waste of money for this.

Comment: _"91% alcohol, It removes anything applied to a material"_ - I've encountered plenty of "anythings" that disagree ;)  But I agree, ethanol (or isopropanol) is a good start.